# type transfer int to str

Tags: python, types

Question:
   Given a string containing uppercase alphabets and integer digits (from 0 to 9), write a function to return the alphabets in the order followed by the sum of digits.

My Code:

```
import re

class Solution:
    def rearrange(self, str):
        # Write your code here
        if str == "":
            return str
        sum = 0
        letter = []
        for i in range(len(str)):
            if re.search("([A-Z])", str[i]):
                letter.append(str[i])
            else:
                sum += int(str[i])
        letsort = sorted(letter)
        letstr = "".join(letsort)
        result = letstr + str(sum)
        return result
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/Main.py", line 20, in
    ans = solution.rearrange(str)
  File "/code/Solution.py", line 20, in rearrange
    result = letstr + str(sum)
  TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I don't understand the reason.

Comment: If any of the answers was helpful, please upvote / mark as correct to help others with similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

`str` is a reserved word in Python, and you overwrote it by naming `rearrange()` second parameter `str` as well. Changing the name of `rearrange()` second parameter will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You have named your variable `str` - same name as built-in function for conversion to string. You need to rename it, try this:

```
import re
class Solution:
    def rearrange(self, str_in):
        # Write your code here
        if str_in == "":
            return str_in
        sum = 0  
        letter = []
        for i in range(len(str_in)):    
            if re.search("([A-Z])", str_in[i]):
                letter.append(str_in[i])
            else:
                sum += int(str_in[i])
        letsort = sorted(letter)
        letstr = "".join(letsort)
        result = letstr + str(sum)
        return result
```